# cv2 module not found python3 odroid

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pip

I have a python 3 script which uses OpenCV which isn't working on my Odroid.  The error that I'm getting is `Import error: No module named 'cv2'`.  But when I run the program in python 2 it seems to work fine.  The problem is that when I attempt to install opencv-python using `pip3`, I get this error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python`.  I'm not sure if this is relevant but I've check the `dist-packages` for python 3 which only contains files for `virtualenv` and contains no `site-packages` directory.  When I navigate to `python2.7` there is a `site-packages` and a `dist-packages` directory, but neither of them contain files for `opencv-python`.  I tried building from source as well which didn't work.  I even checked if for some weird reason my IP was being blocked from pypi.com so I ran `curl https://pypi.python.com` and that worked fine.  I also tried to pip install using a proxy but that also resulted in timeout errors and such.  I'm pretty stuck and not sure if pip is the problem or something else is busted with Odroid.  I also get an error that says when using `sudo`,

`The direcotry '/home/odroid/.cache/pip/http' or its parent direcoty is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.  Please check the permissions and owner of that directory.  If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/odroid/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled.  Check the permissions and owned of that directory.  If executing pip with sudo, you may sudo's -H flag.`

So i run with the flag that they specified and I get the same but error but then this, `You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`  And when I run `pip3 -V` and `pip -V` it says that the version is 9.0.1 and I run the upgrade command it says its up to date.

Help would be much appreciated.  If I've left anything out that you think I should put here let me know!

Edit: Forgot to mention I have tried uninstalling and re-installing pip.

Comment: If someone could explain to me why this got down voted that would be appreciated.  I really need help with this issue and if the question that I'm asking isn't clear or if you believe I need to do more exploring on my own I will, rather than just down voting.

Comment: I have this same problem. When opencv is installed with: sudo apt-get install python3-opencv it installs v 4.2 and works. Python3 doesn have problem with "import cv2" but it doesn't detect anything on images. When installed from source with: https://wiki.odroid.com/etc/opencv/installation it installs latest v 4.9 but puthon3 cannot import cv2 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo -H` flag sets what the `$HOME` environment variable should be during the sudo session, so when you are using it, it sets `$HOME=/root`, rather than `$HOME=/home/odroid`

I would run `sudo -H pip3 -V` and see what that gives you, as the cached wheel in the root folder may be old.

If that is the case, try `sudo -H pip3 --upgrade pip && sudo -H pip3 install wheel`, and then `sudo -H pip3 opencv-python` again.